# Binary search for an ArrayBuffer

Tags: algorithm, scala, performance, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So, I have an ArrayBuffer[Signal], in which each Signal has a timestamp (the array is sorted by this timestamp). I want to binary search and return a Seq[Signal] of signals that are inside a certain range. Now it is done with linear search, basically because I come from Java and I'm a newbie in Scala. Which is the best way to do it?

Here's the code:

```
private def getSignalsFromCache(mapId: String, mac: String, startTime: Long, endTime: Long): Seq[Signal] = {

val signals = getCache(VehicleWithMap(mapId, mac))
val result: ArrayBuffer[Signal] = new ArrayBuffer[Signal]()

if (signals.isEmpty) {
  return signals
}

var startIndex: Int = 0
if (startTime > signals.head.timestamp) {

  while (startIndex < signals.size && signals(startIndex).timestamp < startTime) {
    startIndex += 1
  }
}

var finished: Boolean = false
var currentIndex = startIndex
while (!finished && currentIndex < signals.size) {
  val timestamp = signals(currentIndex).timestamp
  if (timestamp > endTime) {
    finished = true
  }
  else {
    result += signals(currentIndex)
  }
  currentIndex += 1
}
result
}
```

Comment: For what I understand, the ArrayBuffer is sorted ascending, is that correct?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes it is

Comment: This seems straightforward.  Replace the `startIndex+=1` with a `startIndex+=half_the_unchecked_length_in_the_correct_direction()`.  It's just a matter of bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dropWhile`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#dropWhile(p:A=%3EBoolean):Repr) & [`takeWhile`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#takeWhile(p:A=%3EBoolean):Repr).
That way, you can save all the mutability and iterations.

**Note:** This is still linear, but it is more functional and more common in **Scala**.

```
private def getSignalsFromCache(mapId: String, mac: String, startTime: Long, endTime: Long): Seq[Signal] =
  getCache(VehicleWithMap(mapId, mac)
    .dropWhile(_.timestamp < startTime)
    .takeWhile(_.timestamp <= endTime)
}
```

*(make sure of test it first, you may need to play a bit with the conditions)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Searching to do a binary search.

```
import scala.collection.Searching._

val signalWithLowerBoundTimestamp = ???
val signalWithUpperBoundTimestamp = ???
val lower = signals.search(signalWithLowerBoundTimestamp)(
    Ordering.by(_.timestamp)).insertionPoint
// If the upper bound is an exact match, add one
// to make sure it's included in the slice.
val upper = signals.search(signalWithUpperBoundTimestamp)(
    Ordering.by(_.timestamp)) match {
  case Found(i) => i + 1
  case InsertionPoint(i) => i
}
val result = signals.slice(lower, upper)
```

Comment: Ordering.by(_.timestamp) is not resolved by the IDE

Comment: If there are multiple signals with the lower bound timestamp, this method might miss some of them, because Searching.search is not guaranteed to return the first matching result.  You could fix that by getting fancy with the ordering, but at this point it becomes simpler and cleaner just to write a binary search.

Comment: @Guillem can you tell me the error that happened? Maybe you need to import Ordering?

Comment: @Matt yeah, you could follow the binary search with a linear search for the edges, but that would hurt the running time if there are many duplicates. I agree that implementing binary search is better if duplicates are a concern.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon The thing is I am very beginner in Scala. Signal is a case class so when I do signals.search(startTime)(Ordering.by(_.timestamp)) the IDE cannot resolve because there is no special ordering defined. My case class is like this: case class Signal(ap: AccessPoint, timestamp: Long, rssi: Double, mac: String = ""). How do I define the ordering and how I call the method search using it? Thanks Brian, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know scala, but here's a binary search that you can compare more functional-styled answers with.  I don't think there's any shame in it.  Note that there's no advantage to doing a binary search for the end index, since you have to copy the elements anyway:

```
private def getSignalsFromCache(mapId: String, mac: String, startTime: Long, endTime: Long): Seq[Signal] = {

    val signals = getCache(VehicleWithMap(mapId, mac))

    var startIndex: Int = 0
    var endIndex: Int = signals.size

    while(startIndex<endIndex) {
        var testIndex: int = startIndex + (endIndex-startIndex)/2
        if (signals(testIndex).timestamp < startTime) {
            startIndex = testIndex + 1
        } else {
            endIndex = testIndex
        }
    }

    while(endIndex < signals.size && signals(endIndex).timestamp <= endTime) {
        endIndex = endIndex + 1
    }
    signals.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
}
```

Note that I included signals at the end with `timestamp == endTime`, because that's what you did... that makes the interface a little weird, though.  Normally a method like this would be written to return signals with `startTime <= timeStamp < endTime`, so maybe you want to think about changing that.